# IOMEGA 500GB hard disk data reccovery

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, warranty

Last year by November I bought an IOMEGA 500GB Prestige hard disk. Yesterday, unfortunately the hard disk fell down from my table. After that incident, when I connect my disk, Windows asks me to format the disk to use, but I didn't format it yet.

Actually, on that hard disk I have about 320GB of data.

I tried all my possible ways to access my disk. I tried using DOS. It shows "data error (Cyclic redundancy check)". I have a 3 year warranty.

Will I be covered under warranty if I report this issue to IOMEGA? Can I get my data back?

Comment: Recovery tends to be somewhat expensive, and really depends on the situation. There's a little extra information that would be of use - is the drive making any unusual noises?

Comment: yeah.. ticking sound in every rotation !

Comment: Its pretty much a goner. ticking sound could mean the drive head is grinding against the platter, what you'd call a crash. There really is nearly nothing you can do at this point other than trying your luck with an RMA

Answer (score 1):

Stop messing with it immediately! If the data is valuable, call a professional data recover specialist and follow their directions to mail them the disk. Your drive may have only minutes of useful operating time left and you are wasting it fooling around.

You can contact [Vantage](http://www.vantagetech.com/) or [Disk Doctors](http://www.diskdoctors.com/) for a quote and more information. (**Not** a recommendation, just for reference.)

Or if your data isn't worth the trouble, just throw the drive out. Physical damage isn't covered under warranty, and the drive will never be reliable again even if you get it working.

If it's in the middle, try putting the drive in the freezer for two hours. It may get working again for a few minutes, assuming all the heads are still attached.

Comment: Well, as long as you didn't say you dropped it... Most times i RMAed a disk, it was simply a case of it 'stopped working', and they didn't ask anything else. That being said, small drops haven't harmed my external disks much, or did the time one flew across the room...

Comment: @david but sir, one of my friend said to try some software. he suggested (http://the-undelete.com/download.php). will it work..? When i connect my disk it gives a ticking sound for every rotation. if possible can u suggest me some professionals in chennai, Tamil Nadu ?

Comment: @Vineeth "Undelete" software is for when you accidentally delete a file. This has nothing to do with (and won't help in) cases of physical failure. I don't think David will know data recovery places in Chennai, but you'll surely be able to do a web search for local businesses.